# No button on login screen for switching between gnome, unity2d

Tags: gnome, login

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04. I installed gnome-shell as well. However, I do not see the button on the login screen which  will allow me to choose between Unity and gnome.

I am using lightdm

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I've recreated greeter in terminal: [image]

Click on the Ubuntu icon right of the username. It must show a menu (something like this):
[image]
Then choose Gnome/Unity2d etc.

Comment: I am using lightdm.